# refreshing php content inside div when input onchange

Tags: php, jquery, page-refresh

I have a simple `<input>` and when user writes there something I need to refresh php inside div so it will look like `some.php?key=thevaluefrominput`. How would I do that? I guess I need to use query but I'm not sure how.
I want something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) when you write something to *Type to find tags* it changes the the tags bellow.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: If everything is already on the page, you don't need to query a php script, you can do the filtering with just javascript.

Comment: yes, use javascript, you should look for the onchange event and then set the inputvalue to the object you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for AngularJS :)
However this is jQuery solution:

```
$(function () { 
  $('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();       
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'some.php',
        data: 'key=' + escape($.trim($('#myinputfield').val())),
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $('#divtopresent').html(data);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

If you mean that while user types (before submission), div content changes? Then remove

```
  $('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

and instead put

```
$('#myinputfield').keydown(function () {
```

There is a setInterval method that I mentioned in comment, so the first chunk of code I posted, replace it with this one:

```
$(function () { 

  var old_val = '';
  var curr_val = '';
  setInterval(function () {

    curr_val = $.trim($('#myinputfield').val());
    if (old_val != curr_val) {
      old_val = curr_val;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'some.php',
        data: 'key=' + escape(curr_val),
        dataType: 'html'
      }).done(function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $('#divtopresent').html(data);
        }
      });
    }

  }, 2000);

});
```

It checks if value of the field changed every 2s, please replace amount in ms (2000) if you like.

Comment: That works great thanks. But the keydown function works little bit slow. For example when I write 'ab' it only shows 'a' then I add 'abc' and it shows 'ab'. Do you know how to solve this issue? @Dalibor

Comment: I don't understand, I get some negative points for answering, what gives? Guess I don't fully understand this stack overflow concept... But anyway: in that case, I would go with setInterval and check every x seconds if the value of the input field changed and then call the ajax.